# Independence of MLEs for subsamples

Tags: probability-theory, independence, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

Suppose I have a sample $\textbf{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ from stationary and $\beta$-mixing time series. I want to estimate the scalar parameter $\theta$ of the distribution using MLE, i.e.,
$$ \hat{\theta}_{MLE} = \text{argmax}_{\theta} \;\mathbf{L}(\theta, \textbf{x}) $$

I am interested in the case when I will take not the full sample, but split it into two subsamples: $\textbf{x}_{1, n/2} = (x_1, \dots, x_{n/2})$ and $\textbf{x}_{n/2 + 1, n} = (x_{n/2 + 1}, \dots, x_n)$ and then I will calculate MLE's based on these two subsamples:
$$ \hat{\theta}_{1, n/2} = \text{argmax}_{\theta} \;\mathbf{L}(\theta, \textbf{x}_{1, n/2}) $$
$$ \hat{\theta}_{n/2+1, n} = \text{argmax}_{\theta} \;\mathbf{L}(\theta, \textbf{x}_{n/2 + 1, n}) $$
Will these estimates be asymptotically independent as $n \to \infty$?

Would be grateful if you'd share any ideas.

Comment: If $(x_1,...,x_n)$ are not necessarily independent this is not true. Take $x_i=x_1$ for all $i=1,...,n$ for instance.

Comment: @jlewk, good point, thank you, I need to impose some extra conditions, one second.
UPD: corrected the assumptions.